# Lane Detector divider lines c ++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Now I have been working on the analysis of images with OpenCV, what I'm trying to do is recognize the lane dividing lines, what I do is the following:

```
1.I receive a image,
2. Then transform it to grayscale
3.I apply the GaussianBlur
4.After I place me in the ROI
5.I apply the canny
6.then I look for lines with hough transform Lines 
7.Draw the lines obtained from hough
```

But I've run into a problem which is:
that recognizes no dividing lines both rail and neither recognizes the yellow lines.

I hope to help me solve this problem, you will thank a lot.
Then I put the code

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linefinder.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int houghVote = 200;
string arg = argv[1];
Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1]);    
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image,gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
   GaussianBlur( gray, gray, Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
    vector<string> codes;
    Mat corners;
    findDataMatrix(gray, codes, corners);
    drawDataMatrixCodes(image, codes, corners);
 //Mat image = imread("");
    //Rect region_of_interest = Rect(x, y, w, h);
    //Mat image_roi = image(region_of_interest);
 std::cout << image.cols << "\n";
 std::cout << image.rows << "\n";
 Rect roi(0,290,640,190);// set the ROI for the image
 Mat imgROI = image(roi);
 // Display the image
 imwrite("original.bmp", imgROI);
// Canny algorithm
Mat contours;
Canny(imgROI, contours, 120, 300, 3); 
imwrite("canny.bmp", contours);
Mat contoursInv;
threshold(contours,contoursInv,128,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
// Display Canny image
imwrite("contours.bmp", contoursInv);

/* 
Hough tranform for line detection with feedback
Increase by 25 for the next frame if we found some lines.  
This is so we don't miss other lines that may crop up in the next frame
but at the same time we don't want to start the feed back loop from scratch. 
*/
std::vector<Vec2f> lines;
if (houghVote < 1 or lines.size() > 2){ // we lost all lines. reset 
    houghVote = 200; 
}else{ 
    houghVote += 25;
} 
while(lines.size() < 5 && houghVote > 0){
    HoughLines(contours,lines,1,PI/180, houghVote);
    houghVote -= 5;
}
std::cout << houghVote << "\n";
Mat result(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(255));
imgROI.copyTo(result);
// Draw the limes
std::vector<Vec2f>::const_iterator it= lines.begin();
Mat hough(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
while (it!=lines.end()) {
    float rho= (*it)[0];   // first element is distance rho
    float theta= (*it)[1]; // second element is angle theta
    if ( theta > 0.09 && theta < 1.48 || theta < 3.14 && theta > 1.66 ) { 
    // filter to remove    vertical and horizontal lines
        // point of intersection of the line with first row
        Point pt1(rho/cos(theta),0);        
        // point of intersection of the line with last row
        Point pt2((rho-result.rows*sin(theta))/cos(theta),result.rows);
        // draw a white line
        line( result, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255), 8); 
        line( hough, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255), 8);
    }
    ++it;
   }

   // Display the detected line image
   std::cout << "line image:"<< "\n";
   namedWindow("Detected Lines with Hough");
   imwrite("hough.bmp", result);

   // Create LineFinder instance
   LineFinder ld;

  // Set probabilistic Hough parameters
   ld.setLineLengthAndGap(60,10);
   ld.setMinVote(4);

  // Detect lines
  std::vector<Vec4i> li= ld.findLines(contours);
  Mat houghP(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
  ld.setShift(0);
  ld.drawDetectedLines(houghP);
  std::cout << "First Hough" << "\n";
  imwrite("houghP.bmp", houghP);

  // bitwise AND of the two hough images
  bitwise_and(houghP,hough,houghP);
  Mat houghPinv(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
  Mat dst(imgROI.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
  threshold(houghP,houghPinv,150,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV); // threshold and invert to black lines
  namedWindow("Detected Lines with Bitwise");
  imshow("Detected Lines with Bitwise", houghPinv);

  Canny(houghPinv,contours,100,350);
  li= ld.findLines(contours);
 // Display Canny image
 imwrite("contours.bmp", contoursInv);

 // Set probabilistic Hough parameters
  ld.setLineLengthAndGap(5,2);
  ld.setMinVote(1);
  ld.setShift(image.cols/3);
  ld.drawDetectedLines(image);

  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << "Lines Segments: " << lines.size();

  putText(image, stream.str(), Point(10,image.rows-10), 2, 0.8, Scalar(0,0,255),0); 
  imwrite("processed.bmp", image);

  char key = (char) waitKey(10);
  lines.clear();
  }
```

The following are the input images respectively:
[image: input 1]
[image: input 2]

Here I show two photos one that recognizes the white line and another that does not recognize the yellow line, what I require is to recognize the dividing lines because I monitor the lane, but is complicated to me and it does not recognize the presence of all dividing lines, I hope help me because I have honestly tried everything but I have not had good results.

[image: Lane]
[image: Lane 2]

Comment: my project is about object following robot with open cv. Are you doing similar project? I ll search for line following robot and see if I can find a solution for your problem

Comment: it would be better if you share your input image & also output

Comment: Now add the images and out, in fact I'm trying to do is a program to help me monitor the lane change a car, through a camera, but at this point I've only worked with pictures, testing whether with different images the algorithm works the same, but I have encountered some problems, really do not understand why it does not recognize the yellow lines and some white lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are doing a bitwise addition of both probabilistic hough and regular hough transforms. This means that the outputted image will only contain lines that appear in both of these transforms. I'm pretty sure in the regular transform the line is not detected but in the probabilistic hough output the line is detected. You're best bet is to output both transforms separately and debug. I'm doing a similar project, I  imagine you could include a separate ROI to exclude from the bitwise addition and that area would be along the centrum of the lane markings.